# How to push values from a dropdown to an array and add the array to a table?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

This is the JavaScript. The select has an `id` of '`counties`'.

The table is to be inserted into a `div` called '`up_bottom`'.

```
var leagueArray = [];
function addTeams() {
  var county=document.getElementById("counties");
  var val = county.options[county.selectedIndex].value;
  leagueArray.push(val);
  function display() {
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    for (var i=0; i<leagueArray.length; i++) {
      var row = table.insertRow();
      for (var j=0; j<leagueArray[i].length; j++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(leagueArray[i]));
      }
    }
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("up_bottom");
    tableDiv.appendChild(table);
  }
  display();
}
```

Comment: And? Are you getting errors in the console? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function addTeams(){
    var leagueArray = [];
    var county=document.getElementById("counties");
    for (i = 0; i < county.options.length; i++) {
       leagueArray[i] = county.options[i].value;
    }
    display(leagueArray);
}

function display(leagueArray) {
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    for (var i=0; i<leagueArray.length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow();
        for (var j=0; j<leagueArray[i].length; j++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(leagueArray[i]));
        }
    }
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("up_bottom");
    tableDiv.appendChild(table);
}

addTeams();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following Steps

1. Get Selected Value from Dropdown
2. Put the Selected Value into Array
3. Create A String of tr element and append it to Table before First tr element